# Insert multiple (fk) data in one of the two phpMyAdmin table

Tags: php, mysql, insert, phpmyadmin

**Hi. These are my structures :

I got 2 tables in phpMyAdmin :

- Class ( classid(pk), className )
- Students ( studentid(pk), classid(fk), studentName )
  1 form.php and 1 form_post.php

I've done this in form.php**

```
include_once("connection.php");


    $className= $_POST["className"];
    $studentName1= $_POST["studentName1"];
    $studentName2= $_POST["studentName2"];
    $studentName3= $_POST["studentName30"];


    $sql = "insert into class(className) values ('$className')";


    mysql_query($sql);

    $lastid=mysql_insert_id();


    $sql2= "INSERT INTO students (studentid, classid, studentName)
            VALUES (' ', $lastid, '$studentName')";

    mysql_query($sql2);
```

**form_post.php :**

```
            <tr>
              <td width="140"><span class="order">Class Name: </span></td>
              <td><span class="order">
                <input name="className" type="text" id="className" size="35" />
              </span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="132"><span class="order">Student's Name: </span></td>
              <td><span class="order">
                <input type="text" name="studentName1" id="studentName1" />
              </span></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
              <td width="132"><span class="order">Student's Name: </span></td>
              <td><span class="order">
                <input type="text" name="studentName2" id="studentName2" />
              </span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="132"><span class="order">Student's Name: </span></td>
              <td><span class="order">
                <input type="text" name="studentName3" id="studentName3" />
              </span></td>
            </tr>
```

It's a form for registering class and students in it.
In phMyAdmin student table, there's a field/column for studentid(pk), a field/column for classid(fk), a field/column for studentName  while this code which I got from my friend got 3 students name field. How to insert the 3 students name into the phpMyAdmin student table's studentName column with the same class foreign key?
The red colored words are the confusing one.
I'm still a beginner and  I tried all the night to get this work. But, I'm still stuck.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use insert multiple rows depending on if you're inserting the same data into the same tables

Always good to escape your values

```
$className= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["className"]));
$studentName1= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["studentName1"]);
$studentName2= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["studentName2"]);
$studentName3= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["studentName3"]);

$sql2= "INSERT INTO students (studentid, classid, studentName)
        VALUES (' ', $lastid, '$studentName1'),
               (' ', $lastid, '$studentName2'),
               (' ', $lastid, '$studentName3')";

mysql_query($sql2);
```

Recommendations:

1.Learn to prevent from MySQL Injections: [Good Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

2.Mysql extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. More reading: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

**Second Solution:**

```
if(!empty($studentName1)) {
  $sql2= "INSERT INTO students (studentid, classid, studentName)
            VALUES (' ', $lastid, '$studentName1')";

  mysql_query($sql2);
}

if(!empty($studentName2)) {
  $sql2= "INSERT INTO students (studentid, classid, studentName)
            VALUES (' ', $lastid, '$studentName2')";
  mysql_query($sql2);
}

if(!empty($studentName3)) {
  $sql2= "INSERT INTO students (studentid, classid, studentName)
            VALUES (' ', $lastid, '$studentName3')";
  mysql_query($sql2);
}
```

Comment: I wonder, what if the $studentname2 is empty? . It will insert the value 'no' in the table right? How do I get rid of this? Thanks :D

Comment: Then you need to write three individual insert queries and check if value exist, then query otherwise no using `if` statement

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After exploring the if statement. I changed the code to be like this :


if (is_null($_POST["studentName2"]) || $_POST["studentName2"]=="") {
$sql2= "INSERT INTO students (studentid, classid, studentName)
        VALUES ('NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL')";
;
} else {
$sql2= "INSERT INTO students (studentid, classid, studentName)
        VALUES (' ', $lastid, '$studentName2')";
}


Is it right ? Thanks :D

Comment: Thank you very much :D. Didn't know that you edited this post and I accidentally commented in this post. Thank you again :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2= "INSERT INTO students (studentid, classid, studentName)
        VALUES (null, $lastid, '$studentName')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2= "INSERT INTO students (studentid, classid, studentName)
        VALUES ('', $lastid, '$studentName')";
```

Comment: Oops, I tried to edit my post and I think I attempted to edit yours by accident. sigh